# sql - INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY return msg

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sql-insert

I have a web app front end that uses nodeJS to facilitate connections and operations on a MySQL backend. I am looking for a way to implement a unique insert that returns an error message if it finds a duplicate key. Is there something I can implement along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO clients set ? ON DUPLICATE KEY //SELECT "Error: Duplicate Entry" 
AS "";
```

From there, what is the best way to retrieve this message and return it to the user on the web front end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141332/node-js-mysql-error-handling this might be helpful if you want something to start with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js MySQL Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141332/node-js-mysql-error-handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is if you use the SQL *Constraint* keyword in the creation of the table like bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    Id int NOT NULL,
    Key varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT UC_ID UNIQUE (Key)
);
```

This way, the server will not allow you at all to insert a duplicate value.

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT INTO users
(full_name,
 login,
 password
)
       SELECT 'Mahbub Tito',
              'tito',
              SHA1('12345')
       FROM DUAL
       WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (
           SELECT login
           FROM users
           WHERE login = 'tito'
       );
```

Comment: thank you for posting the absolutely worst way to possible try and do this!