# running nodejs and mysql, how can I parse the result in client

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

in my c# I have

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

but the content prints "Internal Error" for all err types

**EDIT**
Also tried:

```
pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if(err) {
        var error = new Error("something is wrong");
        callback(error);
    }
```

according to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-mode-exceptions.html, still getting Internal Error for all error types

Also, I do get 200 OK on good requests, what I am trying to do is to print an explanatory message to the client in case of an error

Comment: Are you sure that given credentials are correct?

Comment: that is because the link you provided show how to get AWS Lambda errors,  but here you're getting MySQL connection errors. Check if [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141332/node-js-mysql-error-handling)